# Can this group be a quotient of a dihedral group (and generalization)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is it true that the group $G = \mathrm{GL}_2(\Bbb F_3)$ is a quotient of a dihedral group $D_{2n}$ for some $n$ ?

More generally, can $G$ be the quotient of a group $H$ which fits in an exact sequence $0 \to A \to H \to A' \to 0$ where $A,A'$ are finite abelian groups ? (We could also ask the same question for $G = \mathrm{GL}_2(\Bbb F_p)$ in general...)

I know that $G$ is solvable, so it might be related to extensions of abelian groups. I know that there is an exact sequence $0 \to \Bbb F_3^* \to G \to \mathrm{PGL}_2(\Bbb F_3) \cong S_4 \to 1$ (NB : $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\Bbb F_3)$ acts on the set $X$ of lines in $\Bbb F_3^2$, which has cardinality $4$).
But I'm not sure about my precise question. Thank you!

Comment: Is $G$ generated by two elements $a,b$ with $a^n = b^2 = (ab)^2 =1$ ?

Comment: @reuns : thank you for your comment. I'm not sure how I should solve your question, however. Maybe working with $G/Z \cong S_4$ ? Could you please provide some more help?

Comment: For generators of $G$ see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/generators-of-gl2-mathbbf-3).

Comment: No, because it does not have a cyclic subgroup of index at most $2$, while every quotient of a dihedral group has this property.

Comment: @verret : thank you very much! Do you know if $G$ can be the quotient of a group $H$ which fits in an exact sequence $0 \to A \to H \to A' \to 0$ where $A,A'$ are finite abelian groups ? I know that $H$ is solvable in that case, but since $G$ also is, it doesn't tell me it's impossible for $G$ to be a quotient of $H$

Comment: No, in fact $G$ is not even metabelian. The only abelian normal subgroups of $G$ are the identity, and the center, and the quotient by the center is isomorphic to $S_4$.

Comment: @verret : very nice. Thank you! You could maybe provide an answer (with some references for normal subgroups of $GL_2(\Bbb F_p)$, if you have – I know that $PSL_n(\Bbb F_p)$ is simple for $p>3,n \geq 2$, but I don't know to find all the normal subgroups of $GL_2(\Bbb F_p)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derived subgroup of a dihedral group is cyclic, and this property is inherited by quotients. On the other hand, the derived subgroup of $GL(2,3)$ is $SL(2,3)$, which is not even abelian. (In particular, $GL(2,3)$ is not even metabelian.)

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually, since the non-abelian group $SL_2(\Bbb F_p)$ is the [commutator subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#Special_linear_group) of [$GL_2(\Bbb F_p)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272439) for [$p>2$](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist_2009&task=show_msg&msg=1242.0001), it follows that $GL_2(\Bbb F_p)$ is not metabelian.